# How to write my function with Promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, promise

I am load HTML (external app) into an `iFrame`

I want to "do" something (`callback`) when an element becomes available in my `iFrame`. Here how I wrote it, and I'd like to write this with Promises instead:

```
function doWhenAvailable(selector, callback) {
  console.warn("doWhenAvailable", selector)
  if ($('#myiFrame').contents().find(selector).length) {
      var elt = $('#myiFrame').contents().find(selector);
      console.info("doWhenAvailable Found", elt)
      callback && callback(elt);
  } else {
      setTimeout(function() {
          doWhenAvailable(selector, callback);
      }, 1000);
  }
}
```

Actually instead of using `setTimeout`, I'd like to use `setInterval` to repeat the "find element" until it's found and resolve the "promise".

Comment: I don't see how promises is especially relevant to this. I'd suggest using a MutationObserver instead if you want to improve the logic, but note that they won't work in IE10 or lower. Alternatively you could flip the logic so that instead of the parent window periodically checking the content of the child, you could make the child inform the parent once when the element is available.

Comment: No, `setInterval` does not play nicely with promises

Comment: to make the child inform the parent, I'd need to add code to the child, which I can't. The reason I ask this question is to understand Promises better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you would not use `setInterval`, you just would wrap the timeout in a promise and drop the callback:

```
function wait(t) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, t);
    });
}
function whenAvailable(selector) {
    var elt = $('#myiFrame').contents().find(selector);
    if (elt.length)
        return Promise.resolve(elt);
    else
        return wait(1000).then(function() {
            return whenAvailable(selector);
        });
}
```

Comment: I see, the `return Promise.resolve(elt);` will allow the syntax `whenAvailable("dummy").then(...)`. Excellent. So on the `wait` Promise, `resolve` can be a function? I don't get why we don't have a `resolve()` call, is it implicit? What about the reject? can be optional? Sorry lot of questions, but I think I am almost getting it

Comment: @zabumba Yes, `resolve` is a function, and it's directly called by the timeout. One could also have written  `setTimeout(function() { resolve(); }, t)`. And no, we don't need `reject`, as we never want to error out.

Comment: BTW what if the element never becomes available? I was confronted to that. That's why I though of the idea of using the `id=setInterval(...)` that I could then clear `clearInterval(id)`. That could work with @pedromss proposition. Nevermind. I understand Promises a lot better now. Cheers!

Comment: When the element never becomes available, the promise never resolves and your callbacks wait forever. If you want to use a timeout (max number of attempts) or manually cancel the search, you can accept a second parameter that specifies how and then use `reject`.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping your recursive style, it would have become something like that :

```
function doWhenAvailable(selector) {
  var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
  console.warn("doWhenAvailable", selector)
  if ($('#myiFrame').contents().find(selector).length) {
      var elt = $('#myiFrame').contents().find(selector);
      console.info("doWhenAvailable Found", elt)
      return dfd.resolve(elt);
  } else {
      setTimeout(function() {
          doWhenAvailable(selector).then(function(e) {
            dfd.resolve(e);
          });
      }, config[env].wrapper.timeOutInMs);
  }
  return dfd.promise();
}
```

But I would have tried to avoid recursive calls here

Comment: This code stacks the promises, I'd rather create another function and avoid creating a new promise for each setTimeout

Comment: There is nothing wrong with stacking promises (though you should avoid the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!), creating a promise for every single asynchronous unit is exactly how they were designed to be used

Answer (score 1):

The general idea is to return a promise instead of receiving a callback.

Example:

```
var xpto = function(res) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if(res > 0) resolve('Is greater');
        else reject(new Error('is lower'));
    });
}
```

So in your case:

```
function doWhenAvailable(selector) {

  function work(callback) {
     if ($('#myiFrame').contents().find(selector).length) {
       var elt = $('#myiFrame').contents().find(selector);
       console.info("doWhenAvailable Found", elt)
       callback(elt);
    }
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.warn("doWhenAvailable", selector)
    setInterval(() => work(resolve), 1000);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
function doWhenAvailable(selector) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

console.warn("doWhenAvailable", selector)
  if ($('#myiFrame').contents().find(selector).length) {
      var elt = $('#myiFrame').contents().find(selector);
      console.info("doWhenAvailable Found", elt)
      resolve(elt);
  } else {
      setTimeout(function() {
          doWhenAvailable(selector).then(function(data){
  resolve(data);
});
      }, config[env].wrapper.timeOutInMs);
  }

    }
}
```

And call your function like that:

```
doWhenAvailable("#elemId").then(function(elt){
//do what you want
});
```

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!